# PHP action inside PHP already running

Tags: php

Good Day

I am not sure if this is possible but any advice would be greatly be appreciated.

I have a code in PHP as below and would like to add additional PHP code Not sure how to explain it but maybe if I show code it would make some sence.

```
 <?php
 //Clickatell login
      $user = "##";
      $password = "##";
      $api_id = "##";
      $baseurl ="http://api.clickatell.com";

     $text = urlencode("Recovery Assist Panic Activated (BETA TEST VERSION");

     $to = "'0827910119'";

  ?>
```

The above is the current code I have with some additional extra's not required here. I want to add the following to this code as part of Sitelok page manager

```
 <?php
 //Clickatell login
      $user = "##";
      $password = "##";
      $api_id = "##";
      $baseurl ="http://api.clickatell.com";

     $text = urlencode("Recovery Assist Panic Activated (BETA TEST VERSION");

 <?php if (sl_ismemberof("RecAssist")){ ?>
     $to = "'0827911119'";
 <?php } ?>
 <?php if (sl_ismemberof("Gold")){ ?>
     $to = "'0827952558'";
 <?php } ?>
  ?>
```

The "is a member of" is part of the sitelok code to exclude on HTML where a person does not have access to. I am not sure if I can run another  inside the one running already. I know this can be done with IF and ELS most prob but the coding for the amount of groups will just be too much so hoped that somehow I can use the Sitelok section

Comment: why not just use an if statement?

Comment: I have approximately 30 different groups and it grows so will have to rewrite whole time.

Comment: then make dynamic with a switch statement, you can't put php tags inside php, there is no point, just use the php syntax?

Comment: Your PHP code is invalid. You have a `<?php` inside of another `<?php`. If you have snippets like this which you need to include, why not include it as an external PHP file?

Comment: put your groups and $to#s in an array and loop over it with a foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use an if statement?

e.g.

```
<?php
//Clickatell login
$user     = "##";
$password = "##";
$api_id   = "##";
$baseurl  = "http://api.clickatell.com";
$text     = urlencode("Recovery Assist Panic Activated (BETA TEST VERSION");

if (sl_ismemberof("RecAssist")){
    $to = "'0827911119'";
} elseif (sl_ismemberof("Gold")) {
    $to = "'0827952558'";
}
?>
```

Comment: He stated in the question that this would not be a good option because he has over 30 groups

Comment: So would i be able to add additional elseif below?

Comment: that was after posting answer will revise

Comment: that sl_ismemberof is part of a framework isn't it? could you update question with what that function does?

Comment: The if statement and elseif is going to get congested but I agree TT120 this would be best option and better to work. I will stay with your suggestion of syntax I thought the PHP tags inside would be easier

Answer (score 0):

The best an most maintainable way to achieve this would be to define all of your groups or w/e in an associative array and loop through it because it will be the most maintainable.

```
<?php
//Clickatell login
$user     = "##";
$password = "##";
$api_id   = "##";
$baseurl  = "http://api.clickatell.com";
$text     = urlencode("Recovery Assist Panic Activated (BETA TEST VERSION");

$groups = array(
    "RecAssist" => "0827911119",
    "Gold" => "0827952558",
);

$to = "";

foreach($groups as $k=>$v)
{
    if(sl_ismemberof($k)) // $k is the RecAssist or Gold or w/e
    {
        $to = "'$v'"; // $v is those digits

        // if $groups were to have 100 items or even 1,000 then there is no need to run sl_ismemberof() on the remaining items once we found what we are looking for. It would be a waste of time.
        break; // break out of our loop
    }
}

echo $to;
?>
```